# IntelliJ IDEA not loading dependencies from docker compose - python django

Tags: python, django, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I have set up a remote interpreter from the docker-compose option for a Django project. Still, it is showing me red squiggly lines under the package imports. How can I fix this?

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db && 
            python manage.py migrate && 
            python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=devdb
      - DB_USER=devuser
      - DB_PASS=changeme
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5-alpine3.16
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=devdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=devuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme

volumes:
  dev-db-data:
```

[image: Code ss]

[image: Docker ss]

[image: Docker config ss]